# Chdir fails even though the user has a home directory assigned

Tags: ssh, users, sftp

I'm facing this problem - when I ssh to the server, the user is authenticated correctly, but then the connection is closed with:

> Could not chdir to home directory /home/blazej: No such file or directory.

`getent passwd blazej` shows:

> blazej:x:1002:1002::/home/blazej:

`sshd_conf`:

```
# Begin SFTP-Server block
Match Group sftp
    ChrootDirectory %h
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
#    ForceCommand internal-sftp // This is commented not to force sfto on `sftp` group - I want to be able to ssh with users in `sftp` group
    PasswordAuthentication yes
# End SFTP-Server block
```

luqo33 user belongs to groups: `blazej, sftp`

I do not see why ssh'ing with `blazej` user would fail. On the other habd, sftp works as expected and logs the user to his home dir `/home/blazej`.

Do you have any idea why I ssh'ing in the terminal fails?

Further details:

`ls -la` in /home/blazej :

root@host:/home/blazej# ls -la

```
total 32
drwxr-x--- 5 root   sftp     4096 Nov 21 09:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root     4096 Nov 21 09:00 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 blazej blazej    220 Apr  8  2014 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 blazej blazej   3637 Apr  8  2014 .bashrc
drwxr-x--- 2 blazej www-data 4096 Nov 21 09:00 exports
drwxr-x--- 2 blazej www-data 4096 Nov 21 09:00 imports
drwxr-x--- 2 blazej www-data 4096 Nov 21 09:00 other
-rw-r--r-- 1 blazej blazej    675 Apr  8  2014 .profile
```

Comment: ls -la /home/blazej please

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, I've updated my question

Comment: The user blazej does not own the directory, it does not look right.

Comment: I'd be more worried about the lack of a shell in the `getent` output.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro which directory doesn't the user `blazej` own?

Comment: His own /home/blazej

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro this has actually been amended. The output is a bit outdated.

Comment: @thrig, a passwd entry with no shell defaults to `/bin/sh`.  although that is OS-specific...some default to other shells.  see `man 5 passwd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not see why ssh'ing with blazej user would fail.

The user is `chroot`-ed to his home directory (`%h` is his home directory). This means that consequent `cd` will fail, since the root is for the process `/home/blazej` and there is no `/home/blazej/home/blazej`.

Comment: This seems a bit strange. What's the way out then?

Comment: @luqo33 You can try to pass `-d /` to `sftp-server` in your `sshd_config`. It may help.

Comment: @Jakuje I do not really see how the system would try to chroot to `/home/blazej/home/blazej`. A user's home dir is an an absolute path `home/blazej`. `%h` would also be am absolute directory. It'd not matter where `cd` would be executed.

Comment: Have a look on the manual page for `chroot` to understand this part. It is crucial. Chroot changes root, as advised by name. So after that, user will see absolute directory `/home/blazej` as `/` and than the `chdir` will try to change to `/home/blazej` again, but from the new root, which will effectively end in the described path.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem right know. In order to fix this I set

```
ChrootDirectory /home/%u
```

and changed the user's home directory with

```
usermod -d / <user>
```